# How to check that the user entered a unique value for a DataGridViewColumn?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with `AllowUserToAddRows`=true. The first column is an Id string which has to be unique. What's the best way to check that the Id the user entered hasn't been entered before?

Answer (score 1):

Hook into the [CellEndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx) event, and in the handler use the event arguments to determine whether a) this is a new row and b) it's the ID column. If so, use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) (or similar background technique) to query your data to see if this value is unique. If it isn't, then perhaps making a label visible to the user notifying them of the conflict is the least obtrusive course of action, and don't let the new row commit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an ajax call using jquery to check against values in your database. Or you could create the ID automatically for them using a GUID.

**EDIT** I just saw you're using windows forms... probably can't use jQuery for those :) I would go w/the GUID. You could also attach an onBlur event to the textbox and have it check your database to make sure it doesn't already exist.